# How to convert 2 bounded loop to iteration syntax

Tags: rust, iterator

How can I convert this loop based implementation to iteration syntax?

```rust
fn parse_number<B: AsRef<str>>(input: B) -> Option<u32> {
    let mut started = false;
    let mut b = String::with_capacity(50);
    let radix = 16;

    for c in input.as_ref().chars() {
        match (started, c.is_digit(radix)) {
            (false, false) => {},
            (false, true) => {
                started = true;
                b.push(c);
            },
            (true, false) => {
                break;
            }
            (true, true) => {
                b.push(c);
            },
        }
    }

    if b.len() == 0 {
        None
    } else {
        match u32::from_str_radix(b.as_str(), radix) {
            Ok(v) => Some(v),
            Err(_) => None,
        }
    }
}
```

The main problem that I found is that you need to terminate the iterator early *and* be able to ignore characters until the first numeric char is found.

- `.map_while()` fails because it has no state.
- `.reduce()` and `.fold()` would iterate over the entire `str` regardless if the number has already ended.

Comment: You are using break statements in your loop on an arbitrary condition which you cannot do in a functional iteration approach. This is like the first thing that one should keep in mind while writing functional iteration code. I guess there are ways to achieve this but you surely can't have break statements there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to find the first sequence of digits while ignoring any non-digits before that. You can use a combination of `.skip_while` and `.take_while`:

```
fn parse_number<B: AsRef<str>>(input: B) -> Option<u32> {
    let input = input.as_ref();
    let radix = 10;

    let digits: String = input.chars()
        .skip_while(|c| !c.is_digit(radix))
        .take_while(|c| c.is_digit(radix))
        .collect();
    
    u32::from_str_radix(&digits, radix).ok()
}

fn main() {
    dbg!(parse_number("I have 52 apples"));
}
```

```
[src/main.rs:14] parse_number("I have 52 apples") = Some(
    52,
)
```

Comment: Thank you, that's much more concise.